# Handling boolean values

Tags: javascript, object

Setting default values is one of my favourite things to do when creating JavaScript applications. While working, i came across a bug that could have easily escaped me.

This is how the object is used.

```
var obj = new App({
             imgs: [];
             preload: false
          });
```

This is how the object is defined.

```
var App = function(o) {

    this.imageFolder = o.imgs;

    this.preload = o.preload || true; // the idea is to set a default value of true

    if(this.preload) {

     // preload images here    

   }

}
```

My question is, how do you handle boolean values when using the **||** operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.preload = "preload" in o ? o.preload : true;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that construct is appropriate when assigning boolean values (I'd also be careful doing this with numbers) for just the reason you've given- a `false` value will be considered invalid, even though it's fine and indeed desired.

in your case you could do the assignment with

```
this.preload = o.preload && true;
```

Comment: @Q_the_novice, This returns undefined if `o.preload` wasn't set.  `var o = {};alert(o.preload && true);`

Comment: Or `o.preload === false ? false : true` as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Chad +1 Thanks for pointing that out, did not spent enough time testing.

Answer (score 1):

|| stands for or.  Let's look at some sample values:

```
this.preload = o.preload || true;
```

If o.preLoad = true:

```
true || true is the same as  = true;
```

If o.preLoad = false:

```
false || true always will equal true
```

Since you define o.preLoad as having a default value of false, the statement will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how do you handle boolean values when using the || operator?

Mine is not an exhaustive answer. [@bkail's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609514/handling-boolean-values/3609541#3609541) should do the trick. However, I would like to point out the following:

The `||` operator produces the value of its first operand if the first operand is truthy. Otherwise it produces the value of the second operand<sup>1</sup>.

```
var preload;                     // undefined is falsy
preload = preload || true;
console.log(preload);            // true

var preload = false;             // false is obviously falsy
preload = preload || true;
console.log(preload);            // true

var preload = "";                // empty string is falsy
preload = preload || true;
console.log(preload);            // true

var preload = null;              // null is falsy
preload = preload || true;
console.log(preload);            // true

var preload = "something else";  // a non-empty string is truthy 
preload = preload || true;
console.log(preload);            // returns "something else", the first operand

var preload = {};                // even an empty object is truthy
preload = preload || true;
console.log(preload);            // returns "Object {}"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Source: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) by Douglas Crockford - Page 17

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 this.preload = !o || o.preload == null ? true : o.preload;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
this.preload = o.preload === false ? false : true;
```

If o.preload **IS** `false`, then we set it to `false`, otherwise, it's `true`

You just might want to add a `o = o || {};` at the start to ensure `o` exists

Answer (score 0):

**Just typecast it:**

```
this.preload = Boolean(this.preload);
```

**Or if you don't want non boolean values evaluating to true:**

```
this.preload = typeof this.preload === 'boolean' ? this.preload : false;
```